# Apply same method to many arguments using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a template function that allows me to apply the same method to different objects, while aiming to minimize the number of lines. Here is more or less what I'm trying to do:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

template<typename ...Args>
void clear_all(Args&... args) {
    args.clear()...;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    set<int> b = {4, 5, 6};
    list<int> c = {7, 8, 9};
    map<int, int> d = {{10, 11},  {12, 13}, {14, 15}};
    clear_all(a, b, c, d);
}
```

In case it is not clear enough, this function `clear_all` wants basically to be equivalent to

```cpp
a.clear();
b.clear();
c.clear();
d.clear();
```

I am aware that I can just try with:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void clear_all(T& t) {
    t.clear();
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void clear_all(T& t, Args&... args) {
    clear_all(t);
    clear_all(args...);
}
```

but those are probably too many lines ;)
Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Does it not compile? Pleae include the error mesage in the question

Comment: btw you shouldnt worry too much about the number of lines you need in your code. Less lines is not always "better" code (I'd rather say the opposite is true). The reason why your "I can just try with:" isnt nice is that it is using recursion

Comment: If less lines meant better quality, comments would be bad practise.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov: comment might be misused and so can be see as bad practice :) Can be out of sync with surrounding code. Writing better code and using better name can often remove the need of comment.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hence the "Don't comment bad code, rewrite it." quote.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: code is not necessary bad at first. Most books/tutorials add extra comment for "beginners" who might then think it is good to do similar comment.

Comment: @Jarod42 I meant documentation written in comments, not comments like `++i; // increments i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (since C++17):

```
template<typename ...Args>
void clear_all(Args&... args) {
    (args.clear(), ...);
}
```

---

The important difference between this and your recursive solution is not the number of lines, but the fact that this does not rely on recursion. If you call `clear_all(a,b,c,d)` then one function with 4 parameters is instantiated, instead of 4 functions with different number of arguments as in your recursive solution. This means less work for the compiler without recursion (though probably no measurable difference at runtime).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: fold expression would produce faster code to compile than recursive way in practice (whereas runtime should be similar)

Comment: @Jardo42 good point, tried to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I found this other shorter way:

```cpp
std::apply([](auto&... args) { (args.clear(), ...); }, std::tie(a, b, c, d));
```

Comment: sorry, but I dont get your point. You can write `template<typename ...Args> void clear_all(Args&... args) { (args.clear(), ...); }` in a single line as well (its even shorter), but why would you?

Comment: Lambda is just a way to have anonymous functor/function. For reuse, named function seems better.